# Flash Builder - generate form from database table

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

I've got remote databases on hosting. Can Flash Builder generate Spark Form with similar structure from database table?

Answer (score 0):

Your Flex application will call a backend script that will access your table definition. Depending on your database, statements will differ.

Here is an example using [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html): "SHOW COLUMNS FROM MyTable"

Your application will then iterate on the results and generate fields according to your logic.

Answer (score 0):

Basically yes. 1st of all you need to connect to the service which u are providing from your backend, and then check the follow article :

http://flexedup.wordpress.com/2009/10/12/form-generation-in-flash-builder-4/